# ClassNotFoundException using Play2 + Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, scala, playframework-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I am new to JVM-based world and I am trying to build a test webservice using Scala, Play 2 framework and Hibernate. My problem is Hibernate configuration. My `hibernate.cfg.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/parking-webservice
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            root
        </property>

        <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml" package="models"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and `hibernate.hbm.xml` looks like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping package="models">

        <class name="Server" table="load_balancer_server" schema="parking-webservice">
            <id name="id" column="id"/>
            <property name="url" column="url"/>
        </class>
        <class name="PlateRecognitionLogEntry" table="log_platerecognitionlogentry" schema="parking-webservice">
            <id name="id" column="id"/>
            <property name="plateNumber" column="plate_number"/>
            <property name="confidence" column="confidence"/>
            <property name="countryType" column="country_type"/>
            <property name="time" column="time"/>
            <property name="image" column="image"/>
            <property name="ipAddress" column="ip_address"/>
        </class>
        <class name="User" table="parking_auth_user" schema="parking-webservice">
            <id name="id" column="id"/>
            <property name="token" column="token"/>
            <property name="admin" column="admin"/>
            <property name="username" column="username"/>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

IntelliJ IDEA has generated a Play 2 project for me. It had `controllers` and `views` directories inside `app` directory. I have created `models` package there as well and added my classes there. One of the classes looks like this (generated Java code converted to Scala):

```
package models
class Server {
  private var id: Int = 0
  private var url: String = null

  def getId: Int = id

  def setId(id: Int) {
    this.id = id
  }

  def getUrl: String = url

  def setUrl(url: String) {
    this.url = url
  }

  override def hashCode: Int = {
    var result: Int = id
    result = 31 * result + (if (url != null) url.hashCode else 0)
    result
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do in my controller:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  private val _configuration = (new Configuration()).configure()
  private val _serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(_configuration.getProperties).buildServiceRegistry()
  private val _sessionFactory = _configuration.buildSessionFactory(_serviceRegistry)

  def sessionFactory = _sessionFactory

  def server_get = Action { request =>
    val session = sessionFactory.openSession
    val query = session.createQuery("from Session")
    val servers: Seq[Server] = Scala.asScala(query.list).map({case d: Server => d})
    val responseList = servers.map(s => s.getUrl)
    val result = Json.newObject
    result.set("servers", Json.toJson(responseList))
    Ok(result.toString)
  }
}
```

and I am getting this exception:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ExceptionInInitializerError: null]]
...<unuseful stack trace>...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
...<more stack trace>...
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate.hbm.xml
...<stack trace that refers to my (new Configuration()).configure() call>...
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class models.Server not found while looking for property: id
...<more stack trace>...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.Server
...<stack trace that says URLClassLoader.findClass failed>...
```

I have tried removing `package` attribute from my `.hbm.cfg` and adding fully qualified class names, e.g., `models.Server`, but with no success, getting same error. I either don't know what the fully qualified name for Play 2 classes is or there is some different thing I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The fully qualified class name is `models.Server` for sure. Check your target folder once and see if that class there. Also any reason using hbm xmls rather than annotations? and why not JPA with Hibernate?

Comment: @RP- could you specify which folder is "target" folder? I have tried using annotations, changed my `.cfg.xml` to only contain `<mapping class="models.Server"/>` and similar definitions, but still getting same error - it cannot load my `Server` class. In terms of JPA+Hibernate - requirements for my app: expose and accept data via JSON webservice (REST), access MySQL database, write code in Scala (one module has to be in Scala, others could be Java, eg models). I have chosen Play2 because it is a Scala thing and hostable on Apache webserver. I come from Python+Django background, very new to Java